# ESP32 not using saved WIFI credentials from menuconfig

Tags: esp32, freertos, espressif-idf

Hey all I've been at this for a few days now trying to figure out whats going on with my ESP32.

I seem to not be able to connect to my wifi network. The esp32 outputs this inside the serial:

```
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:4652
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:14244
load:0x40080400,len:3192
entry 0x4008060c
[0;32mI (416) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.[0m
[0;32mI (416) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x400812d4[0m
[0;32mI (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.[0m
[0;32mI (430) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code[0m
[0;32mI (430) cpu_start: cpu freq: 240000000[0m
[0;32mI (430) cpu_start: Application information:[0m
[0;32mI (435) cpu_start: Project name:     IntexSWG[0m
[0;32mI (440) cpu_start: App version:      1[0m
[0;32mI (444) cpu_start: Compile time:     Apr 12 2023 20:48:57[0m
[0;32mI (450) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  df889df50faea8c3...[0m
[0;32mI (456) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v4.4.1[0m
[0;32mI (461) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:[0m
[0;32mI (468) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM[0m
[0;32mI (474) heap_init: At 3FFB8740 len 000278C0 (158 KiB): DRAM[0m
[0;32mI (481) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (487) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (493) heap_init: At 400939B8 len 0000C648 (49 KiB): IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (501) spi_flash: detected chip: generic[0m
[0;32mI (504) spi_flash: flash io: dio[0m
[0;32mI (513) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.[0m
[0;32mI (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.[0m
This is esp32 chip with 2 CPU cores, WiFi/BT/BLE, silicon revision 1, 4MB external flash
Free heap: 269324
[0;32mI (564) wifi_manager: Set STA IP String to: 0.0.0.0[0m
[0;32mI (568) system_api: Base MAC address is not set[0m
[0;32mI (568) system_api: read default base MAC address from EFUSE[0m
[0;32mI (576) wifi_init: rx ba win: 6[0m
[0;32mI (576) wifi_init: tcpip mbox: 32[0m
[0;32mI (580) wifi_init: udp mbox: 6[0m
[0;32mI (584) wifi_init: tcp mbox: 6[0m
[0;32mI (587) wifi_init: tcp tx win: 5744[0m
[0;32mI (591) wifi_init: tcp rx win: 5744[0m
[0;32mI (596) wifi_init: tcp mss: 1440[0m
[0;32mI (600) wifi_init: WiFi IRAM OP enabled[0m
[0;32mI (604) wifi_init: WiFi RX IRAM OP enabled[0m
[0;32mI (1106) phy_init: phy_version 4670,719f9f6,Feb 18 2021,17:07:07[0m
[0;32mI (1196) wifi_manager: [0m
[0;32mI (1199) http_server: Registering URI handlers[0m
[0;32mI (1199) wifi_manager: MESSAGE: ORDER_LOAD_AND_RESTORE_STA[0m
[0;32mI (1200) wifi_manager: No saved wifi found on startup. Starting access point.[0m
[0;32mI (1208) wifi_manager: MESSAGE: ORDER_START_AP[0m
[0;32mI (1220) wifi_manager: WIFI_EVENT_AP_START[0m
[0;32mI (1323) http_server: Registering URI handlers[0m
[0;32mI (1324) dns_server: DNS Server listening on 53/udp[0m
```

I ran the menuconfig and set the needed access point ssid, password, ip address, gateway and netmask:

[image]

So I am not understanding why its not connecting? Can anyone see what could be causing this that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure those options are for connecting to your network? I believe they're for acting as an access point. To confirm, try changing the SSID to something not in use and seeing if you see it advertised.

Comment: @romkey Seems to act the same even with default values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by default values. Did you try what I asked? That would confirm that it's not connecting because those values are for acting as an access point, not for connecting to your network.

Comment: I definitely agree with @romkey you need to configure for station mode. Share the relevant code please. Follow this link: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/c8983219b919bbe4fb2c39dcd28656c1fbd72509/examples/wifi/getting_started/station

Comment: @StealthRT, besides the station mode: Most ESP32-MCUs are only able to use 2,4GHz. If your Access Point is configured to use 5GHz ....